# r - aggregate / substract two variables, rows

Tags: r, aggregate, rows

I'm using the aggregate function for calculating the difference for every observation of two variables,so somehow like this (and the I want to save the result as a new variable) :

data1

```
         Group            Points_Attempt1        Points_Attempt2
  1        1                    10                      5
  2        1                    34                      23
  3        1                    50                      5
  4        1                    10                      12
  5        2                    11                      21
  6        2                    23                      23 
  7        2                    32                      10
  8        2                    12                      10
```

I'm able to do something like this:

```
aggregate(data1[c("Points_Attempt1","Points_Attempt2")],list(data1$group),diff)
```

But I want it for every single observations and I just do not now to select the observations, so somehow the row numbers (here from 1-8).

So I'm searching for the following fourth column (Difference), which I then would like to safe as a new variable:

```
        Group            Points_Attempt1        Points_Attempt2   Difference
  1        1                    10                      5               5
  2        1                    34                      23              11
  3        1                    50                      5               45
  4        1                    10                      12              -2
  5        2                    11                      21              -10
  6        2                    23                      23               0
  7        2                    32                      10               22
  8        2                    12                      10               2
```

I would be highly thankful, if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Why not subtract after the aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mutate_each`

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>% 
     group_by(Group) %>%
     mutate_each(funs(c(NA, diff(.))), 2:3)
```

Or if we need to subtract between the variables,

```
data1 %>%
        mutate(Difference = Points_Attemp1 - Points_Attemp2)
```